# setTimeout(fn,0) triggering before styles have been applied

Tags: javascript, css, settimeout

When I want to yield execution of my javascript and allow the browser to apply styles etc. before I continue, I tend to use the common technique of `setTimeout` with a delay of `0` to have a callback queued at the end of the event loop. However, I came across a situation where this doesn't seem to be working reliably.

In the snippet below, I have an `active` class that applies a transition to the `chaser` element.

When I hover over a target div, I want to remove the `active` class from the `chaser` element, move the `chaser` to a new location, then reapply the `active` class. The effect should be that the `o` should immediately vanish, and then fade in its new location. Instead, both the `opacity` and `top` have the transition applied, so the `o` *slides* from position to position, *most of the time*.

If I increase the inner timeout's delay to `10`, it starts to behave as I originally intended. If I set it to `5`, then it sometimes does and sometimes doesn't.

I would have expected any `setTimeout` to have queued my callback until after the style updates have been applied, but there's a clear race condition here. Am I missing something? Is there a way to guarantee the order of updates?

I'm on Chrome 56 on macOS and Windows, haven't tested other browsers yet.

(I know I can achieve this in other ways such as applying the transition to only the `opacity` property - please consider this a contrived example to demonstrate the particular question about ordering style updates).

```js
var targets = document.querySelectorAll('.target');
var chaser = document.querySelector('#chaser');
for (var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
  targets[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function(event) {
    chaser.className = '';
    setTimeout(function() {
      // at this point, I'm expecting no transition
      // to be active on the element
      chaser.style.top = event.target.offsetTop + "px";
      
      setTimeout(function() {
        // at this point, I'm expecting the element to
        // have finished moving to its new position

        chaser.className = 'active';
      }, 0);
    }, 0);
  });
}
```

```css
#chaser {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
#chaser.active {
  transition: all 1s;
  opacity: 1;
}
.target {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="chaser">o</div>
<div class="target">x</div>
<div class="target">x</div>
<div class="target">x</div>
<div class="target">x</div>
<div class="target">x</div>
```

Comment: what if instead of setTimeout(fn,0) you use requestAnimationFrame. If you do a double requestAnimationFrame then I'd think the browser should be done updating itself.

Comment: @David might work, not sure if it gives any guarantees but I'll do some reading. I'm more concerned about `setTimeout` not doing what I expect though, as I've relied on it in the past, and now I'm wondering what else might be potentially be broken

Comment: @David initial experiments with a single `requestAnimationFrame` show it works most of the time, but not always. I guess a second `requestAnimationFrame` would probably achieve consistency, but then I think that's probably just because you're basically delaying long enough to avoid the race condition - I'd really like something deterministic...

Answer (score 1):

*What you need to listen for is `transitionend` event before doing anything else. You can read up on [MDN about `transitionend` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend). Btw, `setTimeout` should never be used to guarantee timing.*

EDIT: This is for reference after clarification from OP. Whenever a style change occurs to an element, there is either a reflow and/or repaint. You can [read more about them here](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a). If the second setTimeout is ran before the first reflow, then you get the sliding effect. The reason why 10ms will lead to the desired effect is because `.active` class is added after the `offsetTop` property has been adjusted (leading to `transition` property applied after the element has changed it's `offsetTop`). Usually, there are 60fps (i.e: ~16ms per frame) which means that you have a 16 ms window to do anything before the new styles are applied. This is why a small delay of 5ms will sometimes lead different results.

TL:DR - The browser asks JS and CSS every 16ms for any updates, and calculates what to draw. If you miss the 16ms window, you can have completely different results.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to wait for the transition - I want to abort it in the middle if it's in progress, which actually works fine, it's the second part that's behaving oddly, and there should be no transition in that case

Comment: That's because you have a setTimeout inside a setTimeout. The second setTimeout will only be added to the execution loop, only when the first has run, and will only run after the JS main loop has emptied.

Comment: but that's exactly what I *want* to happen. In fact, I originally didn't have the outer `setTimeout` - I did the remove class and change `top` in one step, then did a setTimeout to re-add the `active` class. I added the extra step just in case it was causing the issue, but it wasn't.

Comment: Do you just want to avoid the `sliding in` effect? i.e: If I hover on a target, the `o` just appears?

Comment: I don't *just* want that - as I said in the question I can do that by only applying the transition to `opacity`. I want to understand why it's happening, and in particular if/why `setTimeout` is not reliable here, and if there is a way to guarantee the order of styles being applied

Comment: Oh, missed the last sentence in your answer - on that point, I'm not trying to use it to guarantee *timing*, I was trying to use it to guarantee *ordering* - there are plenty of examples here and elsewhere of people claiming it's enough to push it to the end of the event queue and have things happen in the expected order. My observations seem to contradict that, and that's worrying.

Comment: I think you're confusing CSS transitions with JS execution. CSS transitions are never queued in the JS execution stack. setTimeouts will run whenever the JS stack is empty. Whether or not there's a CSS transition in motion, that's does not matter.

Comment: It's not about the transition itself though - it happens whether or not the transition has completed. It's about applying the `transition` property to the element, and then subsequently triggering the CSS change that should either have a transition applied or not, depending on the preceding change. In this case there should be no `transition` property on the element, and yet when I change `top`, it gets transitioned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135696/discussion-between-bwaxxlo-and-cupawntae).

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a setTimeout() timing method inside another setTimeout() timing method.

My thought is, why not call the both setTimeout() method separately like so:

The first setTimeout() method should execute first, then at end of execution, it should call the second setTimeout() method.

Comment: I don't see how what your suggesting differs from what I have - the second `setTimeout` happens at the end of the execution of the callback for the first `setTimeout`

Comment: Well, what am trying to say is that, calling both setTimeout() methods independently would be preferable.

Comment: It you called them one after the other in sequence, it would stick both callbacks at the end of the event loop queue, and then they would be executed in sequence without another event loop running in between. My goal was to allow the event loop to run (and update the style, which unfortunately didn't happen) between the first and second callback, which is why I structured it the way I did.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working script for moving the chaser:

```
function _( id ) { return document.getElementById( id ); }

window.addEventListener( 'load', function() {

 var targets = document.querySelectorAll('.target');
  var chaser = document.querySelector('#chaser');

 setTopPosition( targets );

function setTopPosition( targets ) {
    for (var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
        targets[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function(event) { 

            chaser.className = '';
            _( 'status' ).innerText = chaser.className; // to inspect the active class

           setTimeout(function() {
               /* at this point, I'm expecting no transition // to be active on the element */

              chaser.style.top = event.target.offsetTop + "px";
      }, 0); 

          // check if charser.className == ''
          if ( chaser.className == '') {
              setClassName();
          } else {
              alert( 0 );
          }

       }); // addEventListener
    } // for
} //function setTopPosition( targets )

function setClassName() {
    setTimeout(function() {

         /* at this point, I'm expecting the element to have finished moving to its new position */

        chaser.className = 'active';
        _( 'status' ).innerText = chaser.className;
         }, 0);
} // function setClassName()

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="chaser">o</div> 

<div class="target">x</div> 
<div class="target">x</div> 
<div class="target">x</div> 
<div class="target">x</div> 
<div class="target">x</div>

<div id="status">status</div>
```

CSS:

```
#chaser { position: absolute; opacity: 0; }
#chaser.active { transition: all 1s; opacity: 1; }
.target { height: 30px; width: 30px; margin: 10px; background: #ddd; }
```

Comment: I don't really think this answers my question - I'll need more time to read through it. Just a note though - you probably don't want to select "community wiki" on your answers

Comment: Am currently using that same code now, and it's working fine.

Comment: Right, but as I said in the question, I could already solve the problem in other ways, I was specifically asking about ordering of style updates. (Also, FYI, in general code-only answers without an explanation aren't considered complete here). Thanks for the input though!